# Expansion of a fraction of exponentials.

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I have this expansion from Kubo Thermodynamics advanced problems textbook which I am not sure how to achieve.

He has:

$$x_{2l}=\frac{1-e^{-\lambda_1}}{e^{-\lambda_2}-e^{-\lambda_1}}$$
$$x_{2s}= \frac{e^{\lambda_1}-1}{e^{\lambda_1}-e^{\lambda_2}}$$

Then they argue that if we take: $\lambda_i\ll 1$ then we get:

$$x_{2l}=\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}\{ 1+1/2 \lambda_2+(1/12)\lambda_2(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)+\ldots \}$$
$$x_{2s}= \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}\{1-(1/2)\lambda_2+(1/12)\lambda_2(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)+\ldots \}$$

What I tried so far is as follows:
since we have:
$$x_{2l} = \frac{e^{\lambda_1}-1}{e^{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}-1} = (\lambda_1+\lambda_1^2/2+\ldots)/(\lambda_1-\lambda_2+1/2(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)^2+\ldots)=$$

$$ = \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}(1+\lambda_1/2+\ldots)/(1+1/2(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)+\ldots)= \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}(1+\lambda_2/2+\ldots)(1-1/2(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)+O(\lambda_1-\lambda_2))$$

It doesn't look similar, can someone help with these derivations?

Thanks.

Comment: Your expansion is problematic because it assumes $\lambda_1 - \lambda_2$ is small, whereas we know only that each individually is small, not the difference.

Comment: @Y.Forman The question says "$\lambda_i\ll 1$" and I think we can interpret that as  $0 \le \lambda_i\ll 1$. Then indeed also $\lambda_1 - \lambda_2 \ll 1$.

Comment: @Andreas I don't know what I was thinking. Of course you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you did is fine, except for a subscript typo (where you miscopied from yourself) and order typo in your last line (I underlined that).

Further, use that

$$
\frac{1}{1+x} = 1 -x +x^2 + O(x^3)
$$

Expanding all terms one order higher than you did gives
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
[...] &=& \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}(1+\lambda_1/2+\lambda_1^2/6 +\ldots)/(1+1/2(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)+(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)^2/6 +\ldots) \\&=&
\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}(1+\lambda_{\underline 1}/2+\lambda_1^2/6 +O(\lambda_1)^{\underline 3})\cdot\\&&
\cdot(1-1/2(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)- (\lambda_1-\lambda_2)^2/6 + 1/4(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)^2+O(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)^{\underline 3}) \\&=&
\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}(1+\lambda_{\underline 1}/2+\lambda_1^2 2/12 +O(\lambda_1)^{\underline 3} )\cdot \\&&
\cdot(1-1/2(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)+ (\lambda_1-\lambda_2)^2/12 +O(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)^{\underline 3}) \\&=&
\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}(1+\lambda_{\underline 2}/2
-\lambda_{1}(\lambda_1-\lambda_2) 3/12 + \lambda_1^2 2/12 + (\lambda_1-\lambda_2)^2/12  +
\\&&
+O(\lambda_1)^{\underline 3} + O(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)^{\underline 3})  \\&=&
\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}\{ 1+1/2 \lambda_2+(1/12)\lambda_2(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)+O(\lambda_1)^{\underline 3} + O(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)^{\underline 3}) \}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

So the first order and second order terms are as in  the textbook's version.

The same procedure can be applied to the second expression.

Comment: I don't think I get the same answer as in the textbook, can you show me this expansion explicitly?

Comment: I put it in the text.

Comment: Is this fine for you now?

Comment: Yes, thanks! @andreas